# Database implementation of simple "like it" functionality

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to implement a functionality working like "Like it" in FB.

I want users to be able to simple click a button under an object they like. Only positive vote.

The thing is I want to remember, what objects they like so I have to keep it in my database. Let's say, there's only one type of object to keep it simple.

The simplest way is to create a table which will implement many to many relation (users to objects).

My questions are:

1. Is it reasonable solution in terms of performance? Table like this would be quite large and used very often. ;)
2. Any better way to do this?

Comment: facebook also uses mysql [mysql facebook](http://www.mysql.com/customers/view/?id=757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it is. Remember to keep indexes on both the foreign keys (better yet, have both keys as a composite primary key)

2) Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is. You won't have any problems deleting/updating likes. As Arjun Khosla said, just don't forget to add keys.

Your database structure could look like this

**object**

```
ID  name
1   post
2   status
```

**like_to_object**

```
ID  objectID    userID  time
1   2           3       1231231231
2   1           5       1231231231
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, the object is an article and have a table db of article lists (unique id), user have own table db for user lists (unique id). Simply thing like WordPress, create a new meta table for object (article). Not only for this purpose you can use this table multiple times for other future purpose

```
    ID             object_id           meta_name            value
(unique ID)  (object/article id)   (meta name value)     (meta value)
```

save the like data in multiple array data, with unique meta name value e.g. 'user_like'. So, later you just need call the current data from meta table `WHERE object_id == article id` and `meta_name == 'user_like'`.

```
//example saving the data into DB

//get current data
//get a row value from meta table where object_id = article id 
//and meta_name = 'user_like'
$current_data = ....;
$array_data = array();
$array_data[$user_id] = array(
   'user_id' => $user_id
);

if( array_key_exists( $user_id, $current_data ) ){
    //user already like, ignore
}
else {
    //prefer to use + instead of array_merge,
    // in some cases array_merge make array data loose its array keys
    $current_data = $current_data + $array_data;
}

//save it back to meta table row
....
```

just my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it... seems like you probably won't need to access what people liked very often, so it might make more sense to instead of having a many-to-many relation, have a table with `userid` and `objectids` where `objectids` is a delimited list of ids.  IOW instead of

```
userid objectid
1      1
1      2
2      1
2      2
```

have

```
table user_likes_data
    userid objectids
    1      1,2
    2      1,2
```

Then

just have a column with a running count of how many likes an `objecti`d has.  Add a column to an existing table that has `objectid` or make a separate table

```
tabe some_table 
    objectid num_likes
    1        2
    2        2
```

That way, in practice usually you would just increment `some_table.num_likes` and append to `user_likes_data.objectid` list.  There would be a lot less rows in `user_likes_data` and less space used overall (should be less space and overhead from having a single cell of delimited values than multiple rows for each liked object).  And in practice on a given page you'd just be selecting `some_table.num_likes` instead of trying to calculate from `user_likes_data`

Comment: You `objectids` column is not normalized, which is not a good practice.

Comment: "I'm sorry, you're not allowed to like this object, too many other people like it already, and the list of them is stored in a varchar.  Perhaps if the users who like the object have smaller id values, we could fit more of them into the list."

Comment: and what if the user deletes a like? I will not be fun and not performant to store it like this..

Comment: @BillKarwin don't store it in varchar then? @ redreggae .. well OP didn't say anything about deleting likes

Comment: if it should be working like FB then deleting have to be implemented

Comment: well i agree that if it were MY script, I'd like to be able to remove a like.  Hell, I'd also make a dislike button! But my point is the OP didn't say that so...if tht's somethine he wants to be able to do then I agree, his originally stated method would be more efficient

Comment: basically point is from what was given in OP, he seems to only want to store the data only.  He gave no reason why.  So for pure storage purposes only, this would be the least amount of storage space.  I fully agree it would not be the best method if he wants to be able to readily retrieve it for things like unliking

Comment: storing a comma seperated list in one column is definitely an antipattern and should be avoided. There is a good book [sql-antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). There is written: `if you simply need to store the full list in a database and retrieve it later in exactly the same format, there’s no need to separate the values`

Comment: well i know i'm now making assumptions, but i'm going to assume that the objectids are probably incremental and would therefore not be the same length, so they would have to be delimited.

Comment: `separate the values` means saving one value per row and not comma seperated. So in some situations you can denormalize the table..but only if you don't need the individual values..

Answer (score 0):

Add a table, say likes:

```
Likes
ID     ID_U     ID_O
1      5        7
2      5        9
3      5        11
4      4        7
```

Where:
`ID_U` refer to the id of the who voted up, `ID_O` for the object.